# Content popup gallery with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

I am trying to create a gallery with modals. Each modal shows a title and some other information but when you click it pops up and other content is displayed. Almost like an image gallery with navigation, but the thumbnail shows something other than the expanded gallery has. To make it more clear I attached a picture with a wireframe.

Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkp5s.png)

Comment: Like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNqaxJ

Comment: Yes sir. It seems like it does what I need. Thank you!